# Default app has already been configured

Tags: objective-c, xcode, firebase, podfile

I know there has been plenty of discussions on the topic, but no answer helped to resolve the bug for me

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: 'Default app has already been configured.'

I have tried with :

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
    {
        if ([FIRApp defaultApp] == nil) {
            [FIRApp configure];
        }

        self.viewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
        return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    }

@end
```

the default app should configure only if **nil**. this is not working though. What seems to be the problem?

this is my **Podfile** :

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'com.notificationTest.fcm' do
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

   # Pods for com.notificationTest.fcm
   pod 'Firebase/Core'
   pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

end
```

Comment: Could you post a stack trace of the exception?

Comment: Your snippet with the nil check actually fixed my issue, thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, check whether you have implemented   FirebaseApp.configure() accidentally twice in your  project

or try below

In AppDelegate.swift override a following method:

```
override init() { FirebaseApp.configure() }
```

In your ViewController.swift's viewDidLoad() method, write this code:

```
if FirebaseApp.app() == nil { FirebaseApp.configure()}
```

[shared from another language swift ]

Comment: my god.... you give an answer in swift and the question is in obj C......